# Repository on DVDs for Ubuntu likes Debian

Tags: dvd, official-repositories

Why Ubuntu dont have all repository on dvds likes Debian?

I downloaded 10 dvds from debian Wheezy... I'm happy... so I no need internet for install programs on my laptop or my student's netbooks... but I would like test ubuntu because it is more friendly for my students, and in my town we dont have internet connection because i ask you ubuntu 12.04 LTS all repository on DVDs links for download them...

Thanks.

P/D: Sorry for my bad english... i from argentina...

Comment: you may contact, [Argentinian Loco Team](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/ubuntu-ar/).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at AptOnCD, but if you're going to download everything anyway, I would suggest that you use apt-mirror to create a local mirror of Ubuntu. That way, everyone in your local network can install and upgrade from your computer without the need for a separate internet connection. So you install security upgrades, for instance, and then those are immediately available to everyone.

apt-mirror can also be started and stopped, so you don't have to download so much at a time.